# Python: Regex unable to find any matches on string

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm having trouble to find the matches with the above code:

```
sample="""[2019-01-02 16:15:17.882][P:1624/T:1420][UIPCall.cpp:743 
CUIPCall::HandleUICEvent()][Enter]
[2019-01-02 16:15:17.883][P:1624/T:1420][UIPCallState.cpp:1776 
CUIPCallIncomingLine1State::HandleUICEvent()][Enter]"""
pattern=r'\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]\[(.+?)(HandleUICEvent|FastNtfClosed_Line1_Common|Login|Logout)\(\)\]\[(.*?)\]$'

p= re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

p.match(sample)
```

it is troubling me because it works on https://regex101.com/r/hw7pyY/1 but does not match anything on python.

It has to be `re.match()` as I need the `.end()` and `.start()` functions.

Comment: `p.match(sample).groups()` ?

Comment: Use `re.finditer`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you redirect me to the duplicate question link.

Comment: It is on top of the post.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i did try the re.finditer function but a found that i also needed the match.end() and match.start() functions. Do you know any other way to make it work with re.match()

Comment: `re.finditer` yields match data objects, so you may access `start` and `end` of each of the matches.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/awwbWl

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew any idea on why it works on regex101?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187114/discussion-between-snakefoot-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and use the preview pane to verify, that your code is well indented. If you expect help from us, we expect some effort from you.